# Gremlin - how to show field value instead label value

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, graph-notebook

with gremlin I want to show a graph with vertex name a field name end not the label name.
How can do it?

If I use this
[my graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ANvb.jpg)

I see the label name and not a specific value field, for example Name field value
How I can modify my query?
Thanks a lot

I want a specific value field for vertex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like you are using the `graph-notebook` Jupyter notebooks. You can use the `-d` and `-de` flags to tell the notebook how to label the diagram. For example:

```
%%gremlin -d name -de weight
```

will label nodes using a "name" property, and edges using a "weight" property.

Note that most of the magic commands, like `%%gremlin` support asking for help. You just need to put at least one character in the cell body. For example:

```
%%gremlin --help
x
```

There is additional documentation [available here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/graph-notebooks.html) and [here](https://github.com/aws/graph-notebook)

There are also a number of sample notebooks that come included with the graph-notebook open source package. Several of those contain examples of how to customize graph visualizations. You may find those useful.

Comment: Hi Kelvin, your example works fine. Now I just want one vertex and all edges. How can I do it?

Comment: Do you mean there are multiple edges between the same vertex pair, or something else?

Comment: multiple edges between the same vertex pair. I find this and it works fine for OUT edge from specific vertex: g.V().has('name','my_value').outE().inV().path().by(elementMap()). Now I want to see all IN edge for specific vertex

Comment: Does the example in this issue (also now included in the sample notebooks) help? https://github.com/aws/graph-notebook/issues/157

Comment: it doesn't work :-( I have an error

Comment: As this is really a different question, it might be best, if the original question is answered, to accept the answer to this question and create a new question that includes what you tried and the error you received.